# How can I make unicode characters from integers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, unicode, nsstring

I want to make an array of Unicode characters, but I don't know how to convert integers into a Unicode representation. Here's the code I have so far

```
NSMutableArray *uniArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
int i;

for (i = 32; i < 300; i++) {
    NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u%04X", i];
    [uniArray addObject:uniString];
}
```

Which gives me an error "incomplete universal character name \u"

Is there a better way to build an array of Unicode symbols? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use %C to insert a unicode character:

```
NSMutableArray *uniArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
int i;

for (i = 32; i < 300; i++) {
   NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", i];
   [uniArray addObject:uniString];
}
```

Another (better?) way is using stringWithCharacters:

```
NSMutableArray *uniArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
int i;

for (i = 32; i < 300; i++) {
   NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(unichar *)&i length:1];
   [uniArray addObject:uniString];
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for these. I used the first one, it was just what I needed.

Comment: The main difference is that `%C` takes a `wchar_t`, which is (currently, and on Mac OS X) 32-bit, so you're passing UTF-32 there. `stringWithCharacters:` takes UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that `\u` must be followed by four hexadecimal digits *at compile time*. You've followed it with “`%04x`”, apparently with the intent of inserting those four hexadecimal digits *at run time*, which is too late—the compiler has long ago finished its work by then, and the compiler is what is giving you this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single UTF-16 character, `[NSString stringWithCharacters:&character length:1]`. If it’s UTF-32, you’d have to convert to surrogate pairs, or use `-initWithData:encoding:`, or try what Philippe said (I’m not sure offhand whether that handle’s UTF-32 properly, but it should).

Answer (score 0):

Yet Another Egregious Example of Regex Usage:

Requires [RegexKitLite](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/regexkit/RegexKitLite-3.1.tar.bz2).  Uses the regex `(?s).` to split a string of unicode characters in to a `NSArray`.  The `.` regex operator matches everything **but** new-line characters by default, and the sequence `(?s)` says `Turn on the Dot All regex option` which allows `.` to match new-line character as well.  Important since we obviously pass over at least `\n` in the example below.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RegexKitLite.h"

// Compile with: gcc -std=gnu99 -o unicodeArray unicodeArray.m RegexKitLite.m -framework Foundation -licucore

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  unichar uc[1024];
  for(NSUInteger idx = 0UL; idx < 1024UL; idx++) { uc[idx] = (unichar)idx; }
  NSArray *unicharArray = [[NSString stringWithCharacters:uc length:1024UL] componentsMatchedByRegex:@"(?s)."];

  NSLog(@"array: %@", [unicharArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(32UL, (1024UL - 32UL))]);

  [pool release];
  return(0);
}
```